# Thread ending, ends the entire program?

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, pthreads

The following loop is inside the main of the program. It accepts an incoming connection, and has a thread do work with it.

The problem is, as soon as any thread terminates, it terminates the entire program. Here's the code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define BUFLEN 1500
#define MAXCON 30

char *returnTimeDate(int inputchoice);
void readWriteToClient(int inputconnfd);

int main(){

    int backlog = 10;

    int fd;
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (fd == -1) {
        // Error: unable to create socket
    }

    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
    socklen_t cliaddrlen = sizeof(cliaddr);

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(5001);

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, (socklen_t) sizeof(addr)) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Bind Didn't Work\n");
    }

    if (listen(fd, backlog) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Listen Didn't Work\n");
    }

    pthread_t *threadsArray = (pthread_t *)calloc(MAXCON, sizeof(pthread_t));
    pthread_t *threadPtr = threadsArray;

    int k;
    for(k = 0; k < MAXCON; k++){
        fprintf(stderr,"Make %d\n",k);
        int connfd;
        connfd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen);
        if (connfd == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"Accept Didn't Work\n");
        }
        fprintf(stderr,"Waited\n",k);
        pthread_create( &threadPtr, NULL, readWriteToClient, (void *)connfd);
        threadPtr++;
    }

    pthread_t *threadPtrJoin = threadsArray;

    for(k = 0; k < MAXCON; k++){
        fprintf(stderr,"Join %d\n",k);
        pthread_join( *threadPtrJoin, NULL);
        threadPtrJoin++;
    }

/*  readWriteToClient(connfd);*/

    close(fd);

    return 0;

}

void readWriteToClient(int inputconnfd){

    int connfd = inputconnfd;

    while(1){

        char *dateString = "DATE\r\n";
        char *timeString = "TIME\r\n";
        char *endString = "end";

        char *bufferTime = returnTimeDate(0);
        char *bufferDate = returnTimeDate(1);

        ssize_t i;
        ssize_t rcount;
        char buf[BUFLEN];
        char *toReturn = (char *)malloc(BUFLEN*sizeof(char));
        rcount = read(connfd, buf, BUFLEN);
        if((strcmp (buf, dateString)) == 0){
            strcpy(toReturn, bufferDate);
        }
        if((strcmp (buf, timeString)) == 0){
            strcpy(toReturn, bufferTime);
        }
        if((strcmp (buf, endString)) == 0){
            goto outside;
        }
        if (rcount == -1) {
            // Error has occurred
            printf("Error: rcount -1");
        }

/*      fprintf(stderr,"I have received = %s\n",buf);*/

        if (write(connfd, toReturn, BUFLEN) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr,"I didn't write = %s\n",buf);    
        }
    }

    outside: return;

}

char *returnTimeDate(int inputchoice){

    time_t timer;
    char *bufferTimee = (char *)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    char *bufferDatee = (char *)malloc(25*sizeof(char));
    struct tm* tm_info;
    time(&timer);
    tm_info = localtime(&timer);
    strftime(bufferTimee, 25, "%H:%M:%S\n\0", tm_info);
    strftime(bufferDatee, 25, "%d:%m:%Y\n\0", tm_info);

    if(inputchoice == 0){
        return bufferTimee;
    }else{
        return bufferDatee;
    }

}
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: Have you made sure the code in the method executes? I've never seen a non-`void *` thread method

Comment: Yeah, the thread works like a charm, just the main program ends. Out of curiosity though, what is the standard convention you referred to?

Comment: What are you doing after creating the threads?

Comment: @Geesh_SO The method declared as `void * readWriteToClient(void * inputconnfd)` and the call being `pthread_create(&threadPtr, NULL, readWriteToClient, (void *)connfd);`

Comment: Are you joining any of these threads?

Comment: Yeah guys, sorry I'll add all of the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that are very wrong with your usage of pthreads.

First of all, I think you meant this:

```
int st = pthread_create(&threadPtr[k], NULL, readWriteToClient, (void *)connfd);
if (st != 0) {
    /* handle error */
}
```

Note the following:

- We're storing the return value of `pthread_create()` in `st` and handling its error case.
- We're passing `&threadPtr[k]` (of type `pthread_t *`), not `&threadPtr` (of type `pthread_t **`). **This was likely the cause of your issue.**

But one of the main issues I have with your code, is that you are invoking undefined behavior by passing `readWriteToClient` to `pthread_create()`. The `pthread_create` prototype is as follow:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict,
                   const pthread_attr_t *restrict,
                   void *(*start_routine)(void*), 
                   void *restrict arg);
```

Even if you change `&threadPtr` to `&threadPtr[k]`, you'd be calling it as follow:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *restrict,
                   const pthread_attr_t *restrict,
                   void (*start_routine)(int),      // oops!
                   void *restrict arg);
```

So, the `pthread_create()` accepts a pointer to a function of one type, but you're passing it a pointer to a function of another type (C11, 6.7.6.3/15, emphasis mine):

> **For two function types to be compatible, both shall specify compatible return types**.
>   Moreover, the parameter type lists, if both are present, shall agree in the number of
>   parameters and in use of the ellipsis terminator; **corresponding parameters shall have
>   compatible types**. [...]

The pointer to the function is implicitly converted, and your function is called anyway, but this is illegal, as per the standard (C11, 6.3.2.3/8, emphasis mine):

> A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a
>   function of another type and back again; the result shall compare
>   equal to the original pointer. **If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the
>   behavior is undefined**.

Since you are invoking undefined behavior, there's no telling how the code will behave after you do.

Also, keep in mind that converting an `int` to a `void *` and back is not guarantee to happen without loss of information (it's implementation-defined), so be careful with that.

There are a few other errors in your code that you should see if you **compile with warnings enabled, something you should *always* do.**

Answer (score -1):

I bet your compiler was yelding some warning about incompatible pointer type....

My suggestion is **TO FIX EVERY WARNING** during the compile phase.

If this was done, you'd notice that the parameter of the pthread function must be a pointer to void and not an int.

Plus, the latter function must return a pointer to void and not just void that can produce a big mess with the stack.

First, use an array of connection fds

```
int connfd[MAXCON];
```

then save the connfd in

```
connfd[k] = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &cliaddr, &cliaddrlen);
```

then, change

```
pthread_create( threadPtr, NULL, readWriteToClient, connfd);
```

with

```
pthread_create( threadPtr, NULL, readWriteToClient, (void *) &connfd[k]);
```

and change

```
void readWriteToClient(int inputconnfd)
```

with

```
void *readWriteToClient(void *inputconnfd)
```

then assign it to the local variable with

```
int connfd = *((int *) inputconnfd);
```

let me know if it works

Comment: Why not `int connfd = (int) inputconnfd;`?

Comment: because, according to my fixed version, inputconnfd now is a pointer to void

Comment: -1 for wrong and dangerous advice. `pthread_create( threadPtr, NULL, readWriteToClient, (void *) &connfd);` is **not valid** (and if it were, the cast to `(void *)` would be unnecessary and redundant) unless you add strong synchronization to ensure that the new thread reads the value before it changes or goes out of scope. Passing `connfd` by value is preferable in most cases, but it needs to be cast to `(void *)`.

Comment: you're right about the pointer to connfd. I should have specified that connfd must be taken from an array of int. BUT also pass an int to a function expecting a pointer is WRONG! In my system for example, an int has size of 4 byte while a pointer is 8 byte!

Comment: Fixed... now i don't see anything wrong with it. If you agree with me, please remove the -1